# UIImageView not cropping to circle

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uikit

I have a `UIImageView`. For some reason, the circle crop is not working properly. What it winds up doing is cropping the edges to a circle, but leaves the sides completely straight, any ideas why?

Here is my code:

```
self.avatarTwo.layer.cornerRadius = self.avatarTwo.frame.size.height /2;
self.avatarTwo.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.avatarTwo.layer.borderWidth = 0;
```

The image is 2448 by 3264 (pixels) and this is how it looks right now cropped:

[image]

Comment: Can you show an image of what is actually happening? Perhaps some more information on the view containing your UIImageView etc.

Comment: would you please show a complete piece of code?

Comment: See edits on the image property. Andrey, this is the complete.

Comment: This looks like a scale to fit issue. Set the `UIImageView`'s to scaleToFill. `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the UIImageView is square, the UIImage's height is much larger than the width. The default content mode for UIImageView is `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` which scales the content "to fit the size of itself by changing the aspect ratio of the content if necessary." To make the image centered and filling the UImageView you must use:

```
self.avatarTwo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

See [contentMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewContentMode) for more information on this.

In essence, your UIImageView is being cropped fine, but the content in that image view is being scaled to not crop any of the content.